# Ignore i And j’s same value in loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, if-statement, printf

**I want to print feasible solutions by adding up the maximum combinations of 2 indexes for n indexes where no index’s value can be added to itself**

> Expected output for 4 indexes 1,2 1,3 1,4 2,1 2,3 2,4 3,1 3,2 3,4 4,1
>   4,2 4,3

*Where I’m going wrong :: (Here’s my Code )*

```
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=1; j!=i && j<n; j++)
    {
        printf("%d,%d",i,j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is you have specified `j!=i` because of which your inner loop will exit as soon as it encounters a condition where `j` is not equal to `i` and will not continue for further values.

You just want to skip the iteration when `i == j` for which you should use the `continue` statement.

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{ 
    for( j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if(i==j) continue;
        printf("%d,%d", i,j)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The loop will terminate when `j!=i` if that is part of the condition. You want to check that within the loop and continue the loop afterward. Since the condition is false when i and j are equal, it will do nothing for that iteration and continue onto the next.

It also seems that you want `<=` instead of just `<` if you want to include `n` itself.

```
int n = 4;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        if (i != j)
        {
            printf("%d,%d ", i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is  a solution that till now nobody has suggested.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int n = 5;

    for ( unsigned int i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( unsigned int j = 1; j < n; j++ )
        {
            ( void )( i != j && printf( "%d,%d ", i, j ) );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1,2 1,3 1,4 2,1 2,3 2,4 3,1 3,2 3,4 4,1 4,2 4,3
```

As for your code then this loop

```
for(j=1; j!=i && j<n; j++)
```

stops all iterations as soon as `j == i`. For example for i = 1 and j = 1 the loop will be entirely skipped.

Comment: Thanks for the out of the box solution.

Comment: yeah, far more illegible and maintainable.... the `(void)` cast is unnecessary also. Congrats!

Comment: @LuisColorado The void cast allows to escape warnings that can be considered by the compiler as errors.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, the `void` cast only makes `lint` to make a comment, the compiler doesn't comply if you ignore the result value.  This comes from K&R C, and it's not going to be eliminated.  Most legacy functions do return something (being the most significant example the `printf(3)`  function)  I've seen that only in _in excess_ pedantic programmers that seem not know that the compiler will not comply about.

Comment: @LuisColorado gcc issues an error at www.ideone.com.

Comment: ***an error!!!*** gcc? I have been using plain `printf(3)`s in gcc since year 1993, and older compilers since 1981, and never got even a warning from the compiler.... Also, typecasting something you are not going to use is involving in-excess code in a compiler that does not optimize.

Comment: @LuisColorado Open the reference www.ideone.com. Select the language tag C99. Remove ( void ) and try to compile the program,.

Comment: just done... please... tell me why [this example](http://www.ideone.com/50ftEe) doesn't give an error? is uses `printf(3)` function, which is know as returning a `ssize_t` value, it is called ignoring the returned value, and it doesn't comply about it.  I have plenty (and you have) of examples like this, starting with the simplest, an assignment always returns a value of the type of the lvalue being assigned.  Do you write something like this?  `a = sin(1.0);`  as `(void)(a = sin(1.0));`  ??? really?  8-.

Comment: @LuisColorado I do not want to discuss the peculiarities of the compiler. The fact is that without casting to void in the provided by me program the compiler issues an error. Functions by definition have side-effect.

Comment: @LuisColorado I can not explain this.

Comment: well, it is because **you are wrong**.  I am writing C code for more than 40 years now.... I have seen what you say many times... but never got an explanation different from what you give.  It's simply false.  It has no fundament, as every statement in C is an expression (followed by `;`) the need of casting should apply to **every statement in C**.  That's simply not true.  I have always tried the same statement without the cast, always I have seen it written somewhere... never, never got even a warning.

Comment: @LuisColorado I am not wrong. Did you run the original program at www.ideone.com as I pointed out? The compiler issues an error. So why am I wrong?

Comment: By the way, never a compiler warning is considered an error.  An error makes the compiler not to generate an executable.  A warning is never an error.  You always get a valid executable from a warning message, but probably not doing what you want, as when you write `if (a = b)` instead of `if (a == b)` (which can be exactly what you mean, but the compiler gives you a warning except if you (that aren't forced to) write a new par of rounding parenthesis around the test expression.

Comment: I'll try.. let me check.... because the problem is exactly the same, converting a boolean (`int`) expression into `void`.

Comment: You are `double` wrong, as [this is the result you demanded](http://www.ideone.com/iPGTCr).  Even no warning at all.  Probably your mistake can be elsewhere.

Comment: @LuisColorado Please select the language tag C99.

Comment: no... i don't have to.... but anyway... I'll try that.  I don't have to adhere to the C99 standard... or even to the C12 or any other....

Comment: @LuisColorado Here is the error message issued by the compiler prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:11:19: error: value computed is not used [-Werror=unused-value]
            i != j && printf( "%d,%d ", i, j );
                   ^~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

Comment: @LuisColorado See my comments above. I already pointed this for you.

Comment: yeah.... and you can filter the output of the previous runs over a fake shell script that simply emits the error you want.... as a wrapper... and then you can get any error you want.  This way you'll get a complete C compiler that refuses any valid line as an error, and refuses to compile it.... you have written a C compiler.  I have also send bug reports to the gcc team and have been answered that feeding the assembler with invalid input is not a bug, but a feature.

Comment: @LuisColorado You repeated several times that I am wrong. Why am I wrong? I demonstrated that the compiler indeed issues an error. Maybe it is a compiler bug. But I provided a demonstrative program that will be run even using this version of the compiler and its options set.

Comment: You are wrong because you say that using a cast to `void` is necessary to avoid compiler errors, and it is not necessary to avoid compiler errors, If you configure a compiler to give warnings about some legal construction in the language, you are being over pedantic (nothing bad on that) but never say that it is an error not following your recomendation.  I told you the cast was not necessary, and you told me it was, because some compiler complaint... Well, no compiler complaints, but you can configure a compiler to complain about any construct you do, and not all can be configured so.

Comment: Indeed, some times over casting is an error, as with the result of `malloc(3)`, as it is a bad programming habit to correct the warning the compiler gives when you don't `#include <stdlib.h>` by casting the value of `malloc(3)`.

Answer (score 1):

The error here is that you should not evaluate the i!=j condition as your for loop condition because this will lead to the termination of the loop. The condition needs to be checked inside the loop as a separate condition. You can use if statements to achieve this.

```
for(i = 1; i < n; i++){
    for(j = 1; j < n; j++){
        if(i != j)
            printf("%d,%d", i, j);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's an unusual, aconventional, idiosyncratic [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style).  Please use one of the conventional C styles — either Allman (which is what I use) or one of the variants of 1TBS.

Answer (score 0):

You want to skip the loop when i == j, but your code stops the loop,

```
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=1; j<n; j++)
    {
        if( i != j )
           printf(“%d,%d”,i,j);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are checking condition in inner loop ie in j loop 
So you are checking condition j!=i in inner loop , because of these if condition get false then it will not executed the j loop ,

Dry run :-

Consider the value of n is 4 ...

first i=1 , i<=4 true , then it will goes into j loop , then j=1 and its check 
j!=i means 1!=1 , the condition false here , therefore it not execute j loop and goes again in i loop .....

int main(){

```
    int n;

    printf("\nENTER THE NUMBER OF INDEXES : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(int i=1 ; i<=n ; i++){

            for(int j=1 ; j<=n ; j++){

                    if(i!=j)
                            printf("%d %d    ",i,j);
            }
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
```

}